# How will TV Noise look like If we remove the Cosmic Microwave Background?

Tags: cosmic-microwave-background

People have been saying that a small amount of noises you see in the Analog TV is from the CMB and other devices. What if the CMB never existed and the TV never got affected by devices? (Maybe in space?) Will we see the noises? What will the color be?

Comment: Possibly  answered, or at least related, at: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5264/is-x-noise-on-tv-due-to-big-bangs-background-radiation

Comment: @count_to_10 I've seen the question and It doesn't seem to answer my question. My question is what will it _look like_?

Comment: you will see the same, even the myth says that the contribution of CMB is only 1%, likely below the threshold fo human perception of noise

Comment: perhaps what you would like to know is how white noise from the CMB isolated from other noise will look like

Comment: I witnessed an experiment where the antenna of a VHF receiver was moveable and at the frequency it was tuned at there was no radio station. Hence noise only. When it was directed towards the sky the noise increased.

Comment: @Urgje Maybe like I mentioned above, if you move it into space, maybe it will eliminate the devices that are interfering with the antenna, leaving just the CMB.

Comment: @brucesmitherson So you mean the CMB is white and what you are trying to suggest is that how white noise from the CMB look like when you eliminate other noise?

Comment: no I didnt say it was white noise, I was saying that whatever it looks like, you must isolate it to watch it because it is masked by a huge amount of other noises. I do not know how it would look like in a tv screen

Comment: @brucesmitherson So you mean by not isolating the CMB, we isolate other noise than CMB?

Comment: No, by isolate the CMB I mean to filter out or diminish the other sources of noise so you can watch the CMB in full.

Comment: @brucesmitherson But I think isolating other noise is even harder, because what if there are other causes that science don't know? Maybe trying to eliminate CMB by throwing the antenna far far away?

Comment: science at most talks about the known unknowns, it can never talk about unknown unknowns.

Comment: @brucesmitherson So you mean practically my question is impossible?

Comment: no, it is not impossible, that is how the CMB was discovered, after taking into account all other noises there was some left that could not be eliminated. First an unknown unknown, then a known unknown now a known known.